# What is the inconsistency in pixels colors?

Tags: python, numpy, io, python-imaging-library, binaryfiles

This program gets the r, g, b, a values of a pixels two ways. One by converting into a 2d array of tuples and reading the values. The other uses the default PIL method. However they give me different reading of RGB values. I tried few tests to make sure they were reading the same pixel, but it still gives different values. (This happens when the picture has more than one color)

```
import PIL
import numpy

from PIL import Image


image = PIL.Image.open("image.png")
pixels = image.load()
a = numpy.asarray(image)    

r, g, b, c = a[x][y]
print(str(r) + "," + str(g) + "," + str(b))
r1, g1, b1, c1 = pixels[x2,y2]
print(str(r1) + "," + str(g1) + "," + str(b1))

#print statements arent the same, they dont even add up to the same number.
```

Comment: Why do you use x,y and x2,y2 if you want to address the same pixel?
What's the output?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I tried on a couple of images and the two approaches returned exactly the same values. Keep in mind that `a` is a transpose of `pixels`. This means that you have to use `a[i, j]` and `pixels[j, i]` to target the same pixel!